# UINavigationController.viewControllers and UINavigationBar.items get out of sync... how?

Tags: ios, uinavigationcontroller, uinavigationbar, uistoryboard

Has anyone seen the `UINavigationController.viewControllers` stack and the `UINavigationBar.items` get out of sync on apps built with storyboards?

I started running into this on my app, but it only appears on the iPhone version, not the iPad. It's a Universal app, the only difference are the storyboards. And it only happens on the segue between two specific scenes (my app has 16 scenes total). In each case I start with `MainMenuVC`, push on a `MenuA_VC`, then `MenuA_2_VC`.  The `UINavigationBar.items` list have the titles [ "Main Menu", "MenuA", "MenuA_2"] all of which is expected.

The problem occurs when I hit the back button on the navigation bar of the `MenuA_2_VC`. The view controller pops off to display  `MenuA_VC` as expected, BUT the NavigationBar says "Main Menu" instead of "MenuA" (?!) and there's no back button to return to the `MainMenuVC`.

I wrote a bit of code to examine what's going on... this method is called in the `viewWillAppear` method of all three VCs.

```
+(void) logViewControllerStack:(UIViewController*)vc
    { 
    NSLog(@"ViewControllerStack of %@ = { ", NSStringFromClass([vc class]));
    NSArray* viewControllerStack = vc.navigationController.viewControllers;
    for (UIViewController* vc2 in viewControllerStack) {
        NSLog(@"\t\t%@", NSStringFromClass([vc2 class]));
    }
    NSLog(@"}");
    NSLog(@"NavigationBarStack = { ");
    NSArray* navigationBarStack = mv.navigationController.navigationBar.items;
    for (UINavigationItem* ni in navigationBarStack) {
        NSLog(@"\t\t%@", ni.title);
    }
    NSLog(@"}");
}
```

Sure enough the two stacks get out of sync... I first see it in `MenuA_2_VC.viewWillDisappear`.  The `UINavigationController.viewControllers` has two items (expected), but `UINavigationBar.items` has one (unexpected).  I've tried replacing the segue and rebuilding both scenes in the story board, but nothing works. These are normal push segues with no fancy scaling or transitions. So I'm  not even sure how this is happening or where to look.  Any suggestions?

Comment: Are you getting any warnings or errors in the console? Make sure you're not pushing in code as well as using a segue.

Comment: Console is clean. Pushing VC's is a good guess, @rdelmar, but this code doesn't do it except in very rare, and unrelated circumstances. (e.g. help pressed from an AlertView).

Comment: I'm out of ideas then. The only time I've seen this kind of thing is when there were multiple transitions going on at the same time. If you can post your project somewhere, I could take a look at it.

Comment: I've seen this when I tried to set new UINavigationController.viewControllers() inside a -viewWillAppear callback. Looks like the navigation bar tries to sync up with the navigationController inside -viewDidAppear:, and that is causing this out of sync for me.

Comment: Here is a minimal example to reproduce the issue. http://pastebin.com/Ef8Z6yWW. The title of the navigation bar should represent the color of the view controller. So RED should show up with a view controller that's colored in red, and GREEN for the other. This example shows RED (old navigationItem.title) with a green colored view controller.